# How can I upload post without photo in this code? (Flutter&Firebase)

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart

I made code which upload the post on Firebase.
This code is the upload code.
but I don't know how to upload a post with no photo.
When posts include photos, I can upload them to firebase, but I can't upload without a photo.

code link: https://github.com/HighschoolStudentDeveloperYoon/Q1

Answer (score 0):

In your *_uploadFile* method first check if the *file variable* has content;

```
if (_image != null) {
   //put file to your storage and retrieve downloadURL
}
```

& if it doesn't have any content just pass *null* to your Firestore 'photoUrl' key.